# pandas from 2D data to 1D with multiindex columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a simple 2D dataframe with index and columns. I need to export it to an excel file by using my colleague's layout, e.g. a single row with a multiindex columns of 2 levels. The first level corresponds to my dataframe index, the second level corresponds to my dataframe column.

What I have:

```
          Ah-Step    Wh-Step     T[°C]
C-Rate                                
1C     -30.133791 -63.016814  30.86355
2C     -25.557269 -51.937002  37.10111
3C     -20.338776 -40.632206  43.84840
4C      -8.023851 -16.609749  45.63529
5C      -3.868425  -8.111969  46.74843
```

What I want:

```
          1C                              2C                              3C  \
     Ah-Step    Wh-Step     T[°C]    Ah-Step    Wh-Step     T[°C]    Ah-Step   
0 -30.133791 -63.016814  30.86355 -25.557269 -51.937002  37.10111 -20.338776   

                             4C                             5C            \
     Wh-Step    T[°C]   Ah-Step    Wh-Step     T[°C]   Ah-Step   Wh-Step   
0 -40.632206  43.8484 -8.023851 -16.609749  45.63529 -3.868425 -8.111969   


      T[°C]  
0  46.74843
```

My solution so far (my dataframe is held by the '`Summary`' variable, '`writer`' is for export to excel):

```
m_cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([Summary.index.tolist(),
                            Summary.columns.tolist()])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=pd.np.zeros((1,15)),
                  columns=m_cols)
for c in Summary.index:
    for k in Summary.columns:
        df[c,k].iloc[0] = Summary.loc[c,k]
df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Summary')
```

My solution lacks resistance to change and is not elegant.

Is there an embedded method to do something like this without for loops and pre-allocating a row with zeros?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to move the column index into a new row index level:

```
In [61]: df.stack()
Out[61]: 
C-Rate         
1C      Ah-Step   -30.133791
        T[°C]      30.863550
        Wh-Step   -63.016814
2C      Ah-Step   -25.557269
        T[°C]      37.101110
        Wh-Step   -51.937002
3C      Ah-Step   -20.338776
        T[°C]      43.848400
        Wh-Step   -40.632206
4C      Ah-Step    -8.023851
        T[°C]      45.635290
        Wh-Step   -16.609749
5C      Ah-Step    -3.868425
        T[°C]      46.748430
        Wh-Step    -8.111969
dtype: float64
```

On the plus-side, this automatically builds the MultiIndex for you. On the downside, this is a Series, not a DataFrame, and it is oriented vertically, not horizontally. To fix that, call `to_frame` and then transpose:

---

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Ah-Step': [-30.133791, -25.557269, -20.338776, -8.023850999999999, -3.868425], 'T[°C]': [30.86355, 37.10111, 43.8484, 45.635290000000005, 46.74843], 'Wh-Step': [-63.016814000000004, -51.937002, -40.632206, -16.609749, -8.111969]}, index=pd.Series(['1C', '2C', '3C', '4C', '5C'], name='C-Rate')) 
result = df.stack().to_frame().T
print(result)
```

yields

```
C-Rate         1C                              2C                       \
          Ah-Step     T[°C]    Wh-Step    Ah-Step     T[°C]    Wh-Step   
0      -30.133791  30.86355 -63.016814 -25.557269  37.10111 -51.937002   

C-Rate         3C                            4C                       \
          Ah-Step    T[°C]    Wh-Step   Ah-Step     T[°C]    Wh-Step   
0      -20.338776  43.8484 -40.632206 -8.023851  45.63529 -16.609749   

C-Rate        5C                      
         Ah-Step     T[°C]   Wh-Step  
0      -3.868425  46.74843 -8.111969
```

Answer (score 1):

Or using `unstack`

```
 df.T.unstack().to_frame().T
    Out[139]: 
    C-Rate         1C                              2C                       \
              Ah-Step    Wh-Step     T[°C]    Ah-Step    Wh-Step     T[°C]   
    0      -30.133791 -63.016814  30.86355 -25.557269 -51.937002  37.10111   
    C-Rate         3C                            4C                       \
              Ah-Step    Wh-Step    T[°C]   Ah-Step    Wh-Step     T[°C]   
    0      -20.338776 -40.632206  43.8484 -8.023851 -16.609749  45.63529   
    C-Rate        5C                      
             Ah-Step   Wh-Step     T[°C]  
    0      -3.868425 -8.111969  46.74843
```

Comment: unstack does the opposite of what I want.

Comment: @Wli you mean the my out put dose not meet what you want ?

Comment: Levels are swapped